# Adding a timer button in a frame to another frame

Tags: java, swing, time, jframe

I want to add a timer button to my main frame but it is in another class and I don't know how to use it in my main class.
I need a timer button in my frame but I can't make it without another class.
In that class I can't call my main frame.
This is my code:

```
class ButtonTimer extends Thread{

private JButton button = new JButton(" ");
private int count = 1;
public ButtonTimer() {

    Timer time = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            button.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            count++;

        }
    });

    time.start();

    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
    frame1.add(button);
    frame1.setBounds(0, 20, 100, 50);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.pack();
    frame1.setVisible(true);
}
}

public class game {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
    frame2.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 5000);
    frame2.setVisible(true);

    JLayeredPane jlp = new JLayeredPane();
    jlp.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 500);

    frame2.add(jlp);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ButtonTimer();
        }
    });

}
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want your timerButton should be displayed in frame2??

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 0):

### You Could...

Create a custom `JButton` that wraps a `Timer` internally to it.

This allows you to self contain the button and timer into a single unit and reuse it where ever you want...

### You Could...

Create a custom `Timer` which takes a reference to a `JButton` and updates the text automatically on each trigger...

### You Could...

Create a custom `ActionListener` or even `Action` that takes a reference to a `JButton` and updates the text and then pass this into a `Timer` instance of your choice...

Comment: but how? can you give me an example?

Comment: You take any one of the suggestions and simply add it where you need it...Depending on what you are actually trying to do, you may need a reference to the frame you are trying to effect...

Comment: No, please explain in more details what is you are trying to achieve so I can better ascertain the best solution - This is not a code factory...

Answer (score 0):

Have a try. Here we create a JButton in your main frame and then we set the text on actionPerformed of another class.

```
public class game1 {
    private static JFrame frame2;
    private static JButton button1=new JButton(" ");
public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame2 = new JFrame();
    frame2.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 5000);

    JLayeredPane jlp = new JLayeredPane();
    jlp.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 500);
    jlp.add(button1);
    frame2.add(jlp);

    frame2.add(button1);
    frame2.setVisible(true);
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
       new ButtonTimer();

     }
    });

}

    private static class ButtonTimer {
private JButton button = new JButton(" ");
private int count = 1;
public ButtonTimer() {

    javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                     button.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                     button1.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            count++;
                }
            });
    timer.start();

    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
    frame1.add(button);
    frame1.setBounds(0, 20, 100, 50);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.pack();
    frame1.setVisible(true);
}
    }
}
```